# Scikitlearn MinMax work on column or rows?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, normalization

I have data in shape of 3072 x 64. I want to normalize the data for feeding to a machine learning algorithm. As i remember we need to normalize columns for machine learning (Correct me if i am wrong).
But when i check documentation of [scikitlearn MinMaxScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler), i think it normalize rows instead of column.
Here is the code mentioned in documentation

```
X_std = (X - X.min(axis=0)) / (X.max(axis=0) - X.min(axis=0))
X_scaled = X_std * (max - min) + min
```

So question is that axis should not be 1 if we want to normalize the data? Please help me to understand, i got confusion in it

Answer (score 0):

The '0' axis is probably referred to the [numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/glossary.html) notation, which states:

> Axes are defined for arrays with more than one dimension. A 2-dimensional array has two corresponding axes: the first running vertically downwards across rows (axis 0), and the second running horizontally across columns (axis 1).

To properly understand what it means, look at the `sum` example at the above link.

Therefore, in my understanding, the operation is correctly performed on columns. However, I must say that for people like me, with a 'Pandas background', this may be confusing at a first glance.